# Is it possible to highlight different parts of a div, without making more divs (css, js, html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is for my web developement class project.

I am trying to make a big `<div>`, and inside the `<div>`, I want to highlight different parts of the `<div>`. Since there are a lot of different instances I want to highlight, is it possible to do this without `appendChild` a whole bunch of little `<div>` tags?

For example:

[image]

I am only allowed to use HTML, JS, and CSS.

Comment: No, you can't. You can however use `canvas` to draw those squares if you're allowed to replace the `div` with it.

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question itself, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions. You can use `box-shadow` to highlight without using additional DIV. However the cons of this solution is that you can only highlight one place at the same time.

Sample CSS here:

```
box-shadow: inset 100px 100px 1px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
```

Please refer to [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hktonylee/26ye0to8/5/) for a better demo.